# JSON.stringify() Equal method in Dart or Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

What is `JSON.stringify()` Equal method in Dart or Flutter.

Actually my Backend Services Expecting String Object. How I need to convert From JSON to String Like Below.

**HTTP Request Method**

```
Future<String> createUser(SignupUser data) async {

    NameReq111 req111 = NameReq111(
        firstName: 'dfgdfg',
        lastName: 'KKK',
        email: 'kvr@gmail.com',
        phoneNumber: '9704334584');

    ReqNameObject reqName = ReqNameObject(data: req111);

    var jsncode = jsonEncode(reqName.toMap());

   // It Will Print : {data: {fisrtName:Siva, lastName:Joythi,email:kvr@gmail.com, phoneNnumber:9090909090}}

    print(json.decode(jsncode));

  //It will Print : {"data": {"fisrtName":"Siva", "lastName":"Joythi","email":"kvr@gmail.com", "phoneNnumber":"9090909090"}}

   // But Expected Output Will be:

  // '{"data": {"fisrtName":"Siva", "lastName":"Joythi","email":"kvr@gmail.com", "phoneNnumber":"9090909090"}}'

    final response = await client.post(
      "$baseUrl" + "/urlmethoName",
      headers: {"content-type": "application/json", 'charset': 'UTF-8'},
      body: json.decode(jsncode),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return response.body;
    } else {
      return response.body;
    }
  }

  Output:
```

My Backend Language Expecting below format:

```
'{"data": {"fisrtName":"Siva", "lastName":"Joythi","email":"kvr@gmail.com", "phoneNnumber":"9090909090"}}'
```

How we can do that in Flutter.

Could you please help me. Thanks in advance !!!.

Comment: The official [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) for JSON and serialization could help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use jsonEncode(obj) to generate a String in json format

Comment: @Bastos Look into it once, I tried but it not working.